# PHP combined operator for &&?

Tags: php, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I have code like this:

```
$finalResult = true;

$finalResult = $finalResult && function_01();
// some code here
$finalResult = $finalResult && function_02();
// some many lines of code here
$finalResult = $finalResult && function_XX();
```

And I'm looking for a way how to shorten the code (just for a human-readibility reasons) to something like:

```
$finalResult = true;

$finalResult &&= function_01();
// some code here
$finalResult &&= function_02();
// some many lines of code here
$finalResult &&= function_XX();
```

But of course this doesn't work and operator `&=` is not for boolean values, but for binary.

How should I do this ?
Thanks.

Comment: `$finalResult = function_01() && ... && function_XX()` ?

Comment: @sectus No no, there are many lines of code between Function_01 and Function_XX. I edited question to see it...

Comment: What is there to gain from shortening it? It's perfectly legible.

Comment: @Wrikken It's just about readibility. I like it shortened :)

Comment: Beware && operator is short-circuit. As long as final result is false,  function_02, 03, ... might never be called. Maybe it is your intent, I don't know. Anyway, it is not clear when reading this kind of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after all it seems I will not get it any simpler than original.

For those of you who don't understand why I want to have it in some "short" form - only reason was to have it shorter and nicer. Just the same reason why there is possibility to write `$a += 3` just for beauty.

Anyway, thanks to everybody :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$names = array('function01','function02'...);
$result = true;
foreach($names as $caller)
{
  $result = $result && $caller();
}
```

otherwise instead of $caller() you could look for call_user_func ( https://www.php.net/call_user_func )

it's not really fantastic, but it's shorter :/ not a big deal

**edit:**
uhm... i guess that after your edit this solution is not more functional... should i delete it ?

I would also reconsider the logic of your code by adding a class that makes these checks: if all the checking logic is in a class whose purpose is just that you could surely benefit of readability

Comment: Hmmm those functions must be called on those lines where they are. Rest of the code needs their results. I will think about that `call_user_func` but I hoped for something simple and easy just as `+=` .

Answer (score 1):

Stormsson's but improved - finish as soon as you know the result:

```
$names = array( 'function01','function02'... );
$result = true;

foreach( $names as $caller )
{
    if ( $result == false ) break; // short circuit

    $ret = $caller()
    if ( $ret == false )
    {
        $result = false;
        break; // short circuit
    }

    $result = $result && $ret;
}
```

Comment: Same applies what I wrote to @Stormsson's answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Enrique: now I do not know what you want to accomplish and why

Comment: I just wanted to have some simple and nice solution something like `$a += 3` . That's all. But it seems PHP doesn't provide anything like that.